# Console Commands with ErrorException exit my script instead of continuing after an error

Tags: php, laravel, phpseclib

I just upgraded from 4.2 to 5.0. I got all of my commands working, but I noticed in one script I see an error (an expected error) which reports ErrorException. The problem is, it breaks my script from continuing instead of moving on the the next step in a foreach loop. The same error with the same script on 4.2 will report the error and continue.

4.2: `Cannot connect to xyz.IP Error 60. Operation timed out`

5.0: `[ErrorException]
  Cannot connect to xyz.IP Error 60. Operation timed out`

For more context: I'm using the script to SSH into a couple of servers and run a Ping command. I'm using Phpseclib 1.0. I've tested phpseclib on my old 4.2 build and it works fine. 5.0 is where the problem started occuring.

Does anyone know how I can make the script continue to run after an ErrorException?

```
foreach ($query as $key => $value) {

    $ssh = new Net_SSH2($value->origin_ip);
    $key = new Crypt_RSA();
    $key->loadKey(decryptIt($value->password));

    if (!$ssh->login($value->username, $key)) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    }

    $this->info('    Running Ping');

    //$ssh->setTimeout(1);
    if ($ssh->read('/.*@.*[$|#]/', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX)) {
        //echo "reading";
        //$this->info('    Running Ping');

        //$ssh->setTimeout(4);

        $statusOutput=$ssh->exec("ping -c 1 -W 1 ".$value->destination_ip." >/dev/null 2>&1; echo $? ");

    } else {
        //echo "not reading";
        $this->error("Unable to Read Ping");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To work with exceptions inline within a script, use a `try...catch` block:

```
try {
    $value = someFunctionThatMayCauseAnException();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
}
```

For more information, see the PHP manual entry for [Exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

"Uncaught" exceptions will halt your script. Sometimes, that is the desired effect. For example, the SSH library you're using does not catch the exceptions that occur within the methods, they are allowed to bubble out to the calling script. Maybe your calling script catches them, or maybe you let them keep bubbling to your global exception handler. There are a number of ways to work with exceptions, but the general rule of thumb is that you don't catch them unless you're going to do something with it, like show an error message.

Your script would continue in the previous version because the error was, most likely, emitted as a warning or notice and returning false to indicate failure. With the newer PHP version, the library began emitting exceptions instead, at once indicating failure AND providing an exception object with details about the failure.

This means you'll have to restructure the logic within your loop instead of directly calling the function in a conditional `if`. You didn't specify which line is emitting the exception in your example, but for instance, this is one way that you could restructure to work with exceptions:

```
$errorMessage = false;
try {
    $ssh->login($value->username, $key); // this code is attempted
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // if an exception is emitted 
    // in the try block above, this block
    // is reached. Otherwise, it is skipped
    $errorMessage = $e->getMessage(); 
}

// $errorMessage can only be other than false from the exception catch block above
if ($errorMessage !== false) {
    exit($errorMessage);
}
```

Comment: I solved it. My original code did have  a try/catch block, but I omitted it here. The problem was really stupid. My try catch was using `catch (Exception $e)` but what I needed was `catch (\Exception $e)`. Notice the slash. Saw it in another thread, tried it and it worked. Error is still there, but the script continues which is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. I had a try catch which I modified.

Make sure the `catch` has a backwards slash like this:

```
try {
    //code here
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    print_r($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: This is not always true, only when you're not in the root namespace, and depending on use statements.